# Answer using stable or master?

Tags: discussion

Taking into account that Blender release cycle will be pretty fast from 2.80 up, is it ok to answer using features available in master branch?

Pros:

- Answers could be simpler
- They can be future proof

Cons:

- Not all users are comfortable using not-stable branch
- ???

Personally I'm using master for my daily work without any issues. Also I can see that more and more people in Blender community are using it, but it's only my observation from Twitter/BA/DevTalk/YouTube.

I'm not asking about experimental branches like sculpt or functions. Just master.

My heart say yes, my brain - hell no! What do you think about it?

Comment: At this point it's safe to say a lot of stuff have been ironed out whereas several months ago just the icons underwent several iterations so very little harm could come of this IMO. I agree with both answers below, just make a note that it might not exist currently or at all in the stable version.

Answer (score 6):

I do this already. I don't see why not, but make sure to link the commit where the feature was added (and/or a relevant discussion on the tracker) and include the version number of the release it is expected to be be in.

> X feature doesn't work like that currently, but as of commit [`gf098d0j`](https://just_an_example) (September 12 2029) you can use *magic unicorn button* to get the effect you want. This feature will be in 2.93, or in a recent [development version](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3438/599).

Also of course explain how to use the new feature to solve the OPs question, with the caveat that the explanation applies to how blender works as of now and may no longer apply by the time the release rolls around.

---

The same applies to experimental branches; if there's a branch which solves a problem the OP has, by all means, mention it. Just be sure to note the caveats involved with using it (unstable/maybe hard to install/etc)

Answer (score 3):

I tend to stay with the stable main releases for answers, however that is not to say upcoming feature should not be in answers.

A good example of this was when cycles got the shadow catcher. There was no good way to do that before, so having an answer that pointed people to the daily builds was immensely useful.

Plus when feature X rolls around to the stable build we already have an answer documenting how to use feature X.

Like gandalf said (not *that* Gandalf) if it is clearly labeled that this is a experimental/master/daily build/upcoming feature then there is no reason not to put master branch feature in answers. Its no different then when we answer with a feature and say added in blender 2.xx.

TLDR:

Sure, just make it clear that this feature is not in "normal blender."